# Compiles fine with g++ but fails with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-c++, dialog, macros

I have a perplexing problem with Visual Studio 2015, C++, macros. I do have a bigger project at the background, but the following toy example illustrates the problem.

I have the following C++ code (oma8.rc, oma8.h, oma8.cpp) to create a toy dialog. It compiles with gcc compiler nicely:

windres -O coff -i oma8.rc -o oma8.res
g++ oma8.cpp oma8.res -o oma8

```
// oma8.cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "oma8.h"

using namespace std;

string param2;
int b1, b3;

string GetInputText( HWND dlg, int resid  ) {
HWND hc = GetDlgItem( dlg, resid );
int n = GetWindowTextLength( hc ) + 1;
string s( n, 0 );
GetWindowText( hc, &s[0], n );
  return s;
}

int GetCheck( HWND dlg, int resid) {
HWND hc = GetDlgItem(dlg,resid);
int n = IsDlgButtonChecked( dlg, resid);
return n;
}

BOOL CALLBACK DialogProc( HWND hwnd, UINT message,
                       WPARAM wp, LPARAM  ) {
  switch ( message ) {
    case WM_COMMAND:  {
      int ctrl = LOWORD( wp );
      int event = HIWORD( wp );        
      if ( ctrl == IDCANCEL && event == BN_CLICKED  ) {
        DestroyWindow (hwnd);
        return TRUE;     
      } 
      else if ( ctrl == IDOK && event == BN_CLICKED ) { 
    param2 = GetInputText( hwnd, IDC_EDIT1 );
    b1 = GetCheck( hwnd, RB1 );
    b3 = GetCheck( hwnd, RB3 );  // ignore the other buttons for now
    DestroyWindow (hwnd);
    return TRUE;     
      } 
      return FALSE; 
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:         
      PostQuitMessage(0);         
      return TRUE;
    case WM_CLOSE:
      DestroyWindow (hwnd);
      return TRUE;     
  }

  return FALSE;
}

int main() {

HWND dlg = CreateDialog(  GetModuleHandle(0),
                        MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDD_DIALOG1 ), 
                        0, DialogProc );
MSG msg;

while ( GetMessage( & msg, 0, 0, 0 ) ) {
    if ( ! IsDialogMessage( dlg, & msg ) ) {
        TranslateMessage( & msg );
        DispatchMessage( & msg );
    }
}

cout << "corner text: " << param2 << " as a number: " << atof(&param2[0]) << endl;
cout << "radio1: " << b1 << " radio3: " << b3 << endl;
}

// oma8.rc (stripped 3 comment lines from start)
#include <windows.h> 
#include "oma8.h"

//#include "winresrc.h"  // apparently not needed

LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL

IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOG 20, 20, TABNR(8), THISLINEHEIGHT(15) 
STYLE DS_3DLOOK | DS_SETFONT | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SIZEBOX
//STYLE DS_CENTER | DS_SHELLFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_VSCROLL | WS_POPUP
CAPTION "Caption here"
FONT 10, "Arial"
{
LTEXT           "Corner text",IDC_STATIC,LMARG,UPMARG,60,RHEIGHT
EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1, 60, UPMARG, 60,FIELDH, ES_AUTOHSCROLL
DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,TABNR(5),UPMARG,TABW,FIELDH
PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,TABNR(6),UPMARG,TABW,FIELDH
LTEXT           "Block1, line 1",IDC_STATIC,TABNR(RBCOLUMN),THISLINEHEIGHT(PARAMLINE),TEXTW,RHEIGHT
AUTORADIOBUTTON "B1, line 2",RB1,TABNR(RBCOLUMN),THISLINEHEIGHT(PARAMLINE+1),TEXTW,RHEIGHT,WS_GROUP
AUTORADIOBUTTON "B1, line 3",RB2,TABNR(RBCOLUMN),THISLINEHEIGHT(PARAMLINE+2),TEXTW,RHEIGHT
LTEXT           "Block2 col 1",IDC_STATIC,TABNR(SNGLCOLUMN),THISLINEHEIGHT(CHOICELINE),TABW,RHEIGHT
AUTORADIOBUTTON "B2 col 2",RB3,TABNR(SNGLCOLUMN+1),THISLINEHEIGHT(CHOICELINE),TABW,RHEIGHT, WS_GROUP
AUTORADIOBUTTON "B2 col 3",RB4,TABNR(SNGLCOLUMN+2),THISLINEHEIGHT(CHOICELINE),TABW,RHEIGHT
LTEXT           "Block3, line 1",IDC_STATIC,TABNR(RANGECOLUMN),THISLINEHEIGHT(TXLINE),TEXTW,RHEIGHT
AUTORADIOBUTTON "B3, line 2",RB5,TABNR(RANGECOLUMN),THISLINEHEIGHT(RXLINE),TEXTW,RHEIGHT,WS_GROUP
AUTORADIOBUTTON "B3, line 3",RB6,TABNR(RANGECOLUMN),THISLINEHEIGHT(SCLINE),TEXTW,RHEIGHT
}

// oma8.h (stripped 2 comment lines from start)
#define IDD_DIALOG1     100

// basic buttons
#ifndef IDC_STATIC
#define IDC_STATIC (-1)
#endif
#ifndef IDOK
#define IDOK        40000
#endif
#ifndef IDCANCEL
#define IDCANCEL    40001
#endif

// measures
#define LMARG       6
#define UPMARG      5
#define TEXTW       120 // rb text width
#define TABW        50  // tab width
#define FIELDW      30  // fill-in field w
#define FIELDH      13  // fill-in field h
#define RHEIGHT     14  // row height

// line numbers
#define PARAMLINE       2
#define NOFPARAMS       2
#define OFFSET2         2
#define OFFSET3         5
#define CHOICELINE      (PARAMLINE+NOFPARAMS+OFFSET2)
#define TXLINE          (CHOICELINE+1)
#define RXLINE          (CHOICELINE+2)
#define SCLINE          (CHOICELINE+3)
#define RANGETITLELINE  2
#define RANGEFIELDLINE  (RANGETITLELINE+1)
#define DETECTORLINE    (CHOICELINE+OFFSET3)
#define THISLINEHEIGHT(x)   (UPMARG+(x)*RHEIGHT)

// column numbers
#define TABNR(x)        (LMARG+TABW*(x))
#define RBCOLUMN        1
#define RANGECOLUMN     5
#define SNGLCOLUMN      2
#define DTCTCOLUMN      7

// parameter buttons
#define IDC_EDIT1       1002
#define RB1             1010
#define RB2             1011
#define RB3             1012
#define RB4             1013
#define RB5             1014
#define RB6             1015
```

and oma8.exe (all commands given in a console) opens a dialog that looks exactly as I want it to, hooray. But, I have reasons that I must compile this also with VS2015. (It will be later inserted into a certain boilerplate code, but that's not relevant here.)

When trying to compile the same code with VS2015, I get a bunch of error messages related to the .rc file, especially on its macro functions. The first 4 are

> Error RC2112  BEGIN expected in dialog        oma8.rc 11
>   Error RC2135  file not found: 0x00040000L     oma8.rc 12
>   Error RC2135  file not found: here        oma8.rc 14
>   Error RC2135  file not found: 10      oma8.rc 15

Furthermore, if I change the lines

```
#define THISLINEHEIGHT(x)   (UPMARG+(x)*RHEIGHT)
#define TABNR(x)        (LMARG+TABW*(x))
```

into

```
#define THISLINEHEIGHT(x)   (UPMARG + (x) * RHEIGHT)
#define TABNR(x)        (LMARG + TABW * (x))
```

I get just one error message:

> Error RC2104  undefined keyword or key name: *   oma8.rc 11

I must have something funny with my linker/compiler options? When creating this as a Project From Existing Code, I chose Console App and left all other choices as defaults. (Can't remember what those were, sorry, just lots of acronyms.)

I've spent over a week googling and trying different modifications, but haven't been able to fix this. I don't know what else to try. Where should I look into? Any ideas and further questions would be welcome.

My system is Win7, 64-bit. g++ version says g++ (tdm-1) 5.1.0 (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation Inc.

Comment: RC compiler can't evaluate expressions. `DIALOG 20, 20, 100, 100` is a valid statement. `DIALOG 20, 20, (6+50*(8)), (5+(15)*14)` is not - but the latter is what your macros produce.

Comment: Thanks, that would explain it. But can it be true? VS2015 should understand macros according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593.aspx .

Comment: Yes, RC compiler does "understand" macros. It doesn't understand the result of expanding those macros. It is not the preprocessor that evaluates expressions: the result of expanding, say, `TABNR(8)` is `(6+50*(8))`, not `406`. The preprocessor only performs simple text substitutions.

Comment: That's a big surprise to me, I always thought preprocessor does evaluate expressions. Well, the one within gcc/windres does, at least. You should make your reply into an "answer" so I can mark it as the correct one and you get deserved kudos. :-)

Comment: The difference is not in the preprocessor, but in the compiler proper. I'm pretty sure it's windres compiler itself, not the preprocessor, that knows how to do math, whereas Microsoft's RC compiler doesn't. Would be easy to test: take out one `TABNR(8)` and manually replace it with `(6+50*(8))` (so you have an expression that the preprocessor wasn't involved with). I predict windres would still accept it, and RC would still choke on it.

Comment: That's right, everything involving an asterisk makes RC choke. But interestingly, it does understand plus and minus math(!?) That is, the expression `(200+200)` evaluates to 400 and `(200+200-50)` evaluates to 350. The golden rule to learn from this is "you can add and subtract, but thou shall never multiply!" Oh well.